# How can i get seperate urls for images from html as follows http(s)://<hostname>/<chosenpath>/1

Tags: html, google-app-engine

I am new to appengine and html and need some assistance.
I have deployed the following html file to appengine but I nee to get urls for all images as follows http(s)://hostname/chosenpath/1 (i.e 1 for image 1 and so on)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>




<figure1>
<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/ccws-cw1-bucket/e4.jpg" alt="Glasgow city" width="500" height="333" title="Glasgow City">
 <figcaption>Glasgow City located in Scotland</figcaption>
</figure1>


</figure2>
<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/ccws-cw1-bucket/image.jpg" alt="Islamabad city" width="500" height="333" title = "Islamabad City">
 <figcaption>Islamabad City is the capital of Pakistan</figcaption>
</figure2>



</figure3>

<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/ccws-cw1-bucket/Istanbul.jpg" alt="Istanbul city" width="500" height="333", title = "Istanbul City">
 <figcaption>Istanbul City is a city in Turkey</figcaption>
</figure3>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is not valid HTML at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially do the following

1. Have a special path like `http(s)://hostname/chosenpath/img/1`. Here `img` is a special folder in your path
2. Write a route handler to process any route that ends in `/img/` where you then go manually retrieve the file and return it to the user. You can also do a redirect from here to the `https://storage.googleapis.com` url

You can also keep the url path you mentioned but add code to determine that the file being requested by user is an image file (check that it ends in .png, jpg, etc) and then you redirect the user to the `https://storage.googleapis.com` url